# Как исправить такую ошибку?

Tags: java, android

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:21.+.
>        Versions that do not match:
>            25.0.1
>            25.0.0
>            24.2.1
>            24.2.0
>            24.1.1
>            + 9 more
>        Required by:
>            SotisAndroid:app:unspecified

Answer (score 1):

В android sdk manager деинсталируйте android support repository, а после установите заново. Решение взято [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090248/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-appdebugapkcopy)

Comment: Теперь выдает следующее: Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:21.+
Install Repository and sync project E:/AndroidProject/SotAn/app/build.gradle">Show in File open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: Все оказалось банально просто: отсутствовали некоторые строковые переменные в strings.xml